# Interpolation for between two poses

Tags: ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I am looking for a function which interpolate between two poseStamped poses for a given time. I know there has to be something withing the tf/tf2  API but I could not find it. Something along the line of

poseStamped = poseInterpolation (poseStamp_t1,poseStamp_t2, t)    where  t_1 < t < t_2

Would be glad for some pointers.

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299691/interpolation-for--between-two-poses/) by [Fabs89](https://answers.ros.org/users/32631/fabs89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-08-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd recommend looking at: https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/7ea64d25a0631fe91bd277e0d9195f18cc437151/tf2/src/cache.cpp#L176-L196 which uses the internal fork of the Bullet Linear Math library.

I'd recommend you implement your own version using the pure bullet API.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a solution using Eigen.

The stamped poses (poseStamp_t1 and poseStamp_t2 in your notation) have a timestamp and a pose. The timestamps can be saved to variables t1 and t2, such as t1 = poseStamp_t1.header.stamp.toSec().

The poses can be converted to Eigen with the function tf::poseMsgToEigen (const geometry_msgs::Pose &m, Eigen::Affine3d &e), obtaining Eigen:Affine poses aff1 and aff2. From here, the rotation and the translation part can be interpolated separately. Here is how:

```
// C++ code

#include <Eigen/Geometry>

// Take poses at times t1 and t2. Interpolate the pose at time t.
Eigen::Affine3d pose_interp(double t, double t1, double t2, 
                            Eigen::Affine3d const& aff1, Eigen::Affine3d const& aff2) {
  // assume here t1 <= t <= t2
  double alpha = 0.0;
  if (t2 != t1)
    alpha = (t - t1) / (t2 - t1);

  Eigen::Quaternion<double> rot1(aff1.linear());
  Eigen::Quaternion<double> rot2(aff2.linear());

  Eigen::Vector3d trans1 = aff1.translation();
  Eigen::Vector3d trans2 = aff2.translation();

  Eigen::Affine3d result;
  result.translation() = (1.0 - alpha) * trans1 + alpha * trans2;
  result.linear()      = rot1.slerp(alpha, rot2).toRotationMatrix();

  return result;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [oleg.alexandrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/53591/oleg.alexandrov/) with karma: 11 on 2020-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the PoseStampeds into TransformStampeds, put them into a BufferCore, and then do a tf lookup for any time within the t1 and t2 range:

```py
import tf2_ros
from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped

# get pose1 and pose2 from somewhere, their header.frame_ids needs to be the same,
# or need another transform that supplies the transform from one to the other
...

# probably needs to be non-negative
time_elapsed = pose2.header.stamp - pose1.header.stamp
# or any value >= time_elapsed (not sure if it needs to be > or >=)
buffer_core = tf2_ros.BufferCore(rospy.Duration(time_elapsed))

ts1 = TransformStamped()
ts1.header = pose1.header
ts1.child_frame_id = pose_frame
ts1.transform.translation.x = pose1.pose.position.x
ts1.transform.translation.y = pose1.pose.position.y
ts1.transform.translation.z = pose1.pose.position.z
ts1.transform.orientation = pose1.pose.rotation
buffer_core.set_transform(ts1, "default_authority")

# then do same thing as above for ts2
ts2 = TransformStamped
...
buffer_core.set_transform(ts2, "default_authority")

# now can lookup any stamp from pose0.header.stamp to pose1.header.stamp
buffer_core.lookup_transform_core(pose1.header.frame_id, pose_frame, inbetween_stamp)
```

(adapted from https://github.com/lucasw/tf_demo/blob/old_tf_to_new_tf/scripts/buffer_core_demo.py)